# Nginx: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nginx, bcrypt

I have an express API accessible through a nginx reverse proxy. Everything is working fine except for one handler that uses bcrypt.

My api nginx config:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name api.dev;

ssl_certificate /root/ssl/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /root/ssl/cert.key;

access_log /root/nginx_logs/api_access.log;
error_log /root/nginx_logs/api_error.log;

location / {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://api:8880;

    # Big timeout to test
    proxy_connect_timeout 1200s;
    proxy_send_timeout 1200s;
    proxy_read_timeout 1200s;
}
}
```

My express handler:

```
try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(payload.password, 10);
    return handlerResult.ok({});
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

When I request my api on any other route it works but with this handler nginx get this error:

```
[error] 29#29: *27 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream
```

If I comment `const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(payload.password, 10);` the error dissapear.

At the begining I thought it was a timeout error but as you can see I wrote overkill timeout in nginx.

Thank you, for reading, if you have any question please ask me :)

PS: Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed by using bcryptjs instead of bcrypt !

Comment: searching the whole web, your question puts me in the right direction!